# Do machine specific overrides for a machine configuration required by my custom machine configuration, get used when I build for my custom machine?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded, yocto-recipe

I would like to create a new machine configuration that extends an existing machine configuration.

Let's suppose the machine configuration I want to base mine off of is named foo-mach.conf. My `my-mach` configuration looks like this.

```
require conf/machine/foo-mach.conf

# Remove some stuff not needed.
# Add custom device tree to KERNEL_DEVICETREE.
# Etc.
```

The BSP layer that contains foo-mach.conf contains a lot of machine specific overrides for `foo-mach` in all sorts of recipes.

Will the machine specific overrides for the `foo-mach` machine that `my-mach` requires, get used when I do I bitbake build for `my-mach`?

Edit: solution based on accepted answer

```
require conf/machine/foo-mach.conf

MACHINEOVERRIDES =. "foo-mach:"

# Remove some stuff not needed.
# Add custom device tree to KERNEL_DEVICETREE.
# Etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `MACHINEOVERRIDES`.  For example, `qemu-generic-arm64.conf` includes `generic-arm64.conf` and then extends the overrides with `MACHINEOVERRIDES =. "generic-arm64:"` so that both the current machine and the inherited machine are both valid overrides.